# Query working on SqlServer but not on PHP (more than 4000 characters text field)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am working on an existing PHP code using an undocumented external homemade framework. The database used is Sql Server 2008.

The program gets an Excel file, parses it and saves the data into the database using PDO.
I have no access to the server config, only the code. I can't change the database configuration (the text type can't turn into a VARCHAR type).

One of the values was stopping the execution,

- The error occurs just on the execute() command,
- I replaced the content by a same lenght "Lorem ipsum" (assuming an
  encoding error or anything else), **still not working**,
- I reduced the content lenght, **it worked**,
- I checked into the database to get the data type, it is a **TEXT
  field**,
- I played it again and again to know exactly the limit, this limit is
  4000 characters,

I tried to execute the query on Sql Server (sample):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[database] (tableName, tableId, verifString, inErrorText, code, status) 
VALUES ('DIAG', 123455, 'diag', '[Long string more than 5000 characters]', 'ABC023','anoma')
```

**It worked**

I tried the exactly same query [only changing the id] in PHP (sample):

```
$statement =$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[database] (tableName, tableId, verifString, inErrorText, code, status) 
VALUES ('DIAG', 123456, 'diag', '[Long string greater than 4000 characters]', 'ABC023','anoma')");
$statement->execute();
```

And again, the **execution was stopped**.

If I put a short string into the same query [only changing the id] (sample):

```
$statement =$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[database] (tableName, tableId, verifString, inErrorText, code, status) 
VALUES ('DIAG', 123457, 'diag', '[Short string lower than 4000 characters]', 'ABC023','anoma')");
$statement->execute();
```

**It works**

I searched if there were any restrictions in the homemade framework but I didn't find anything.

Any idea?

I hope my english is understandable. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The text column definition would need to be changed to be able to insert more than 4000 characters. You aren't going to fix that with your code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If the column definition needs to be changed, why is the query working directly on SqlServer?

Comment: Ha, missed that bit! Sorry. I've only ever run into the problem when the length of the column was too low.

Comment: Haha I'm too chatty sry ^^'

Comment: The limit of the text field is 4000 characters. Are you positive that the halted execution isn't caused simply by that limit being exceeded?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on with the PDO? Side note possibly unrelated but that is not how prepared statements are meant to be written. The values should be placeholders and the inputs should be bound. If you make try inserting `$insert_me = str_repeat("a", 4001);` then `$insert_me = str_repeat("a", 3999);` the second is works?

Comment: Can you run it using `->query()` as you are not actually preparing anything useful anyway

Comment: Fillard Millmore: If the limit was 4000 characters I assume that I can't execute the query on SqlServer but it works. No?

Comment: user3783243: $insert_me = str_repeat("a", 4001); is NOK but str_repeat("a", 4000); is OK . I don't know how I can get PDO errors because of the execution crashing the code and I tried to use try/catch around the execute() trying to catch Exception and PDOException but it seems that these are not the right error types.. Maybe anything else?

Comment: RiggsFolly: This is not the real query, the original query ils prepared and the parameters are binded

Comment: You need to use the `@` for notifications to be sent. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php for the error reporting. If unsure please add your connection and your actual query execution (with try catch block)

Comment: user3783243: Great thanks! (there was a \PDO prefix because of the framework and I had to put it in front of \PDOException), I get this error: "SQLSTATE[HY010]: Function sequence error: 0 [Microsoft]"
I'm looking for this.

Comment: Can you try to get information about the extension, which is used for connection to SQL Server? It can be mssql(php_pdo_mssql.dll), sqlsrv(php_pdo_sqlsrv_???.dll) or something else. Maybe <?echo phpinfo()?> will help. Every extension has specific settings and this information may be useful.

Comment: Zhorov: Thanks for your answer. The server is hosting a multiple applications (using Apache/IIS, MySql/SqlServer/PgSql ...). 
This is what phpinfo returns: PHP Extension  20121212, PHP API  20121113 , Registered PHP Streams [...] sqlsrv, PDO drivers  mysql, odbc, sqlsrv, pgsql, sqlite
Is this useful?

Comment: @Amelie Yes. I want to reproduce your error (using sqlsrv extension and prepared statement). But I've inserted text with 8000 characters without errors. If I have time, I''l try to make more attemtps. If you have access to sources, you can search how exactly the connection is made - new PDO( ... ) and then what?

Comment: Zhorov: The connection is usual => $this->database = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password); The error seems to be about drivers (traduction between "#") SQLSTATE[HY010]: Function sequence error: 0 [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC #ODBC driver manager#] Erreur de séquence de la fonction #Function sequence error#(SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)